# UIVIew touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event always receive only one touch

Tags: iphone, ios

touches' count is always 1, even though I put more than 1 fingers on the screen. 
But event.allTouches' count is always correct?
Does this method mean to be function like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable multitouch on the view. Check out the `multipleTouchEnabled` property on `UIView`; it's also available as a checkbox in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enabled multi-touch? It is off by default. From the reference-

> Multiple touches are disabled by default. In order to receive multiple
>   touch events you must set the multipleTouchEnabled property of the
>   corresponding view instance to YES.